# How do I write this c++ snippet with C#

Tags: c#

See the following code in C++:

```
unordered_map<int, vector<int>> indexes;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int tmp = 1;
    indexes[tmp].push_back(i);
}
vector<int>v = indexes[i];
```

How do I write this in C#? So far I've written this:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> indexes = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   int tmp = 1;
   indexes.Add(tmp,new List<int>(i));
}           
List<int> v = new List<int>(indexes[i]);
```

But Im facing issues with the expression
`List<int> v = new List<int>(indexes[i]);` and throws exception:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Add(int)' has some invalid arguments Argument`#1' cannot convert
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' expression to type`int

Comment: You only want to create the new List once outside of the loop.  Then use v.Add(indexes[i]);

Comment: `var v = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
            {                                
                v.Add(i); //or v.Add(indexes[i]);
            }`

Comment: 1) if you want to use `tmp` as a key in the `Dictionary`, you have to change it! It will not allow you to use the same key twice. 2) your error message does not relate to the code you have posted. It complains that you are using a `List.Add` method. But I don't see it in your code. So what is the truth here? the message or the code? The only compiler error I get when I use your code is that `i` is not declared in the scope in this line: `List<int> v = new List<int>(indexes[i]);`. Everything else should work pretty fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error and the code do not relate. This makes the problem not reproducible

Comment: Does it compile? Surely `i` is out of scope in the last line (both C++ and C#)?

Answer (score 1):

`push_back` adds a new element at the end of the vector, which is similar to `List<int>.Add` in C#. Although you can directly `push_back` an item to a vector in C++, you must first create a new `List<int>` before adding things to it in C#:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(i);
indexes.Add(tmp, list);
```

This could be shortened using collection initialisers:

```
indexes.Add(tmp, new List<int> { i });
```